# Trying to import an exported interface in React, but React cannot find it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dependencies

I have two files in the same directory: CosmWasmContext.js, and CosmWasmHooks.js.

This is in my CosmWasmHooks.js file:

```
export interface ISigningCosmWasmClientContext {
    ...
}

export const useSigningCosmWasmClient = (): ISigningCosmWasmClientContext => {
    ...
}
```

I would like to use both the interface and function in my CosmWasmContext.js file. I am able to only import the function useSigningCosmWasmClient, but not the interface.

These are the ways I have tried to import from CosmWasmHooks:

```
import { useSigningCosmWasmClient,ISigningCosmWasmClientContext } from './CosmWasmHooks'
```

```
import { useSigningCosmWasmClient} from './CosmWasmHooks'
import { ISigningCosmWasmClientContext } from './CosmWasmHooks'
```

```
import { useSigningCosmWasmClient} from './CosmWasmHooks'
import ISigningCosmWasmClientContext from './CosmWasmHooks'
```

I can import and use `useSigningCosmWasmClient` without problems. The only issue is with the `ISigningCosmWasmClientContext` interface.

Does anyone know why I might have such strange problems importing? I have never run into this problem before.

Comment: JS doesn't have interfaces. In case you use Flow, the question should focus on it.

Comment: If you are using TypeScript, your file extension must be `.ts`